# Notes on Lachlan's monster

Tags: reference-request, computability-theory

I have been trying to look for a reference I have seen in a paper called **"R. Soare, Notes on Lachlan’s Monster Theorem"** without success. I was wondering if anyone had a digital copy of them at hand and would be kind to share them with me.